# Displaying obersvations multiple time if count is specified

Tags: sas

**I have the following input**

```
FromCount ToCount  FromStore ToStore 
3          1       Macy's    Wallmart
1          3       JcPenny   Frys
3          2       Frys      Wallmart
```

**This is the desired output**

Output

```
FromStore   ToStore  
Macy's      Wallmart
Macy's      Wallmart
Macy's      Wallmart
JcPenny     Fry's
JcPenny     Fry's
JcPenny     Fry's
Frys      Wallmart
Frys      Wallmart
Frys      Wallmart
Frys      Wallmart
Frys      Wallmart
Frys      Wallmart
```

**I have this code:**

```
do i=1 to (FromCount*ToCount);
output;
end;
```

**But that code does not work.**

Comment: I believe, it's not a full code, but a part of the DaTa-step? Then could you please specify what exactly doesn't work? What does log say?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in a Data Step.

```
data output(keep=FromStore ToStore);
set input;

do i=1 to (FromCount*ToCount);
   output;
end;

run;
```

Comment: Nah that wasn't the problem I wasn't sure if my program was generating the right output I tested it again and it works. I thought the do loop was incorrect logic but it works thanks for your answer.

Comment: is there any other way of doing this

Comment: What I have here is the best way to accomplish this in SAS.  I'm sure you could come up with another way but it would not be nearly as compact or efficient.

Comment: @user3305018 - I do think DomPazz has give you the best answer, given the details in the question..